# Simulate fake location on real iOS device

Tags: ios, location, simulate

I want to simulate fake location on my iPhone 5S device using specific longitude and latitude. Is there a way to do this in XCode. I tried using the simulate location feature by adding a GPX file in XCode but it's not working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you don't set your "fake" location to a programatically created location? `CLLocationCoordinate2D CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(   CLLocationDegrees latitude, CLLocationDegrees longitude)`

Comment: `Debug` > `Simulate Location` menu in Xcode **SHOULD** work. we need more info.

Comment: @rintaro: the title contains the words "real iOS device" and your answer applies to simulators

Comment: @donmarkusi It's not about Simulator menu, but Xcode menu. it works on "real iOS device". see:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html

Comment: @AWSSET https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/simulating_location_on_run.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH10l Is this what you looking for?

Comment: oh i am sorry, i didn't know that :)

Comment: @rintaro I tried loading a gpx file in the Simulator menu, but nothing happens.... I also tried adding the gpx file to scheme, but still nothing happens.... Do I need to configure something else?

Comment: Does locations from the menu(e.g. Tokyo,Japan) work? If yes, I think your GPX is corrupted. otherwise, I cannot answer without your code how/when get the location.

Comment: @rintaro Hi! I tried restarting my project and it worked amazingly! thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 41):

It is possible.

You only have to:
1) plug your device to the computer.
2) run an app in the real device (it is the same which application). It is only to have the menu enabled.
3) in Xcode (not in the simulator) Go to menu: Debug -> Simulate Location and select one or add a GPX file.

It will simulate the location not only for the application executed but for all of them.

I suppose that the phone must be in developer mode but if you run apps from Xcode it must be anyway.

I've tested it from Xcode 6 in an iPhone 4 iOS 7.1.2

Hope it helps

Comment: this works but for some strange and not yet investigated reason, it gets confused and swaps between real position and simulated one randomly...

Comment: "but for all of them' this is interesting

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the method for setting a simulated location *at runtime* as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26689515/12484), you can set/change the default simulated location for a default device/configuration *prior to runtime* in Xcode at:

Product (menu) > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Options (tab) > Default Location

[image: Xcode Edit Scheme window with Options tab and Default Location selection shown]