# Spoof location iPhone with flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have been looking for a package that spoofs/mocks location with flutter for iPhone but have not been able to find any. Does one exist or is it only possible through swift?
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use gps-sdr-sim on GitHub and a HackRF SDR to solve this problem. You can pre-define a route using a CSV file with gps-sdr-sim.

Answer (score -1):

You can simulate a location on both a simulator and a real device, however you have to run your flutter app through xCode if you want to simulate location on a real device, see below links for some guidance on where to start.

[Real Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869753/simulate-fake-location-on-real-ios-device)

[Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator)