# Does StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges works in Low Power Mode

Tags: swift, core-location, battery

I want to add **StartmonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** in my app, but does it work in low power mode?

Apple's documentation says that the background activity will turn off, does this apply to **StartmonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**?

Comment: Did you try to just test it? The low power mode is a matter of a single toggle in Settings, and you can trigger location updates, e.g., in Simulator (Features -> Location.)

Comment: But on Simulator you can't turn on low battery mode

Comment: You're right, a real device it is then. You can drain its battery in a natural way (or toggle the mode in Settings.) And there are ways of simulating location change on a real device connected to Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869753/simulate-fake-location-on-real-ios-device